# Add menu item in nw.js doesn't show up on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, nw.js

Trying to add a new menu item to a submenu in NW.js (Node WebKit.) Doing that with

```
if (this.menu.createMacBuiltin) {
    this.menu.createMacBuiltin('Menu');
    this.menuItem = this.menu.items[0];
    isMac=true;
} else {
    this.menuItem = new gui.MenuItem({label: 'Menu'});
    this.menuItem.submenu = new gui.Menu();
    this.menu.append(this.menuItem);
}
this.menuItemSubmenu = this.menuItem.submenu;
```

However, adding a menuItem dynamically like so

```
this.newMenuItem = new gui.MenuItem({label:'New'});
this.menuItmeSubmenu.insert(this.newMenuItem,0);
```

does not work for Windows, but works perfectly for Mac. When I restart the Windows app, the menu item does show up.

Why does Windows not automatically update the menu? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell since you posted only small portion of your code, and didn't mention if you use `node-main` in the config file.

This might be caused due to race conditions - maybe the first code runs after the second. Try to print out `this.newMenuItem.items` just before doing the dynamic insertion. Do you see the existing tray menu?

Try to change `insert` to `append` - did the tray menu item appear?

If both seems ok, try this workaround: instead of adding a new item, rebuild the list. First, empty it using :

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.newMenuItem.items.length; i++){
    this.newMenuItem.removeAt(0);
}
```

Then use `append` to re-add all items. Did it work?

**UPDATE**

The reason I asked if you are using `node-main` is that when you use it, on the main script that you set as `node-main`, while this script is running `window` is not yet defined:

> **window**: defined as a property of 'global', points to the DOM window
>   global object. Note that it would be updated upon page navigation.
>   This symbol is not available at the time the script is loaded, because
>   the script is executed before the DOM window load ([source](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/node-main))

To overcome this you need to run any code that requires the `window` object under your `main` script as configured in the `package.json` file.

Comment: thanks! That last part is close to how I ended up solving this. I did use node-main in config and the first code runs before the second (this also works perfectly on Mac).

Comment: @Gadi I added some more info

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix it.

```
if (windows) {
    this.refreshMenuBar();
}

refreshMenuBar = function() {
    this.menu.remove(this.menuItem);
    this.menu.append(this.menuItem);
    win.menu = this.menu;
};
```

Basically, removing then adding the main menu item, then re-assigning win.menu. For some reason this updates the menu when it doesn't register a change in Windows. After removing and re-adding the entire menu, changes are displayed.